# What is the type of set() in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, types, set

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
b = set(a)
print isinstance(a, types.ListType)
print isinstance(b, types.ListType)
```

The result shows that b is not of types.ListType. However, there is no 'SetType' in Python. So what is the type 'XXXType' so that isinstance(b, types.XXXType) is True?

Comment: `isinstance(a, list)` and `isinstance(b, set)` return True.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `isinstance(b, set)`.

The `types` references to built-in types are just there for convenience<sup>*</sup> and are otherwise deprecated (they have been removed from the [Python 3.x version of the `types` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html)). As such `set` was never added.

For example, `types.ListType` is just an alias for `list`:

```
>>> import types
>>> types.ListType is list
True
>>> isinstance([1, 2, 3], list)
True
```

If you **must** have a `SetType` reference in the `types` module, simply add the alias yourself:

```
types.SetType = set
```

If you are looking for an *abstract base class* for the basic container type, use the [`collections` module ABCs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections-abstract-base-classes); these signal what *methods* a type support and checking against these types can let you detect a wider set of types that support specific operations (rather than be an instance of just the `list` and `set` types):

```
>>> from collections import Set, MutableSequence
>>> isinstance([1, 2, 3], MutableSequence)
True
>>> isinstance({1, 2, 3}, Set)
True
```

---

<sup>*</sup> *History lesson*: Once upon a time, the built-in types like `int` and `list` were not really classes, and the built-in names `int()` and `list()` were simply *functions* to convert to the built-in types. That means that the names were simply not the same object as `types.IntType` and `types.ListType` and you *had* to use the `types` module to be able to use `isinstance()` on a list object. That time is now long, long behind us, and the role of the `types` module has changed.